# Difficult to get an item tapped - Expand hit area

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Image, which I want to get the tap from it (actually the grid that contains it, because it is bigger). But this is not working right, because I have to be really precise when touching the screen to touch the button, otherwise it wont work.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Tapped="DrawerIcon_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Margin="5" x:Name="DrawerIcon"  Source="/Assets/but_drawer.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
```

Is there any way to expand the area of an element that gets hit when I tap?

Comment: I've already tried making the image bigger (changing ScaleX and ScaleY to 1.0), but I does not change much...

Comment: Attaching  event to the container is best way to do this as suggested by @Barnstokkr

Answer (score 1):

The `CompositeTransform` only makes the image larger, to make the Hit area larger you have to do the following:

1. As you did, surround the object (`Image`) with a `Grid`
2. Add the `Tapped` event to the `Grid`
3. The `Margin` of the `Image` will determine the hit area; thus making this larger will make the hit area larger (or anything that makes the `Grid` larger).
4. Finally, and most annoyingly: Make the `Background` of the `Grid` Transparent!

To fix your code, just add `Background="Transparent"` and you can also increase the Margin to 10 if you like:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" Tapped="DrawerIcon_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Image Margin="10" x:Name="DrawerIcon"  Source="/Assets/but_drawer.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
          <Image.RenderTransform>
               <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
          </Image.RenderTransform>
     </Image>
 </Grid
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you suggest, but it does not work... Well, it works, but not as expected. I have to be really careful and precise to get it to work.

Comment: I put a huge rectangle over it and it doesn't work right neither... I just don't know what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I achieve it by making a transparent Rectangle out of every `Grid` over the object that I want to be tapped (only under the root `Grid`) and attaching the Tapped event to it. Apparently being under `Grid`s and `Stackpanel`s affect the Tapped event somehow. This is not a real fix, just a workaround. Maybe it's a bug.